# Event catching from multi instance pool

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bpmn.io, bizagi

I'm modeling a process in BPMN and I have a doubt about this portion of the process.

Specifically I have a multiple instance pool and an another pool. When the first message from the multi instance pool is received by the actor "A", the activity C is performed and then the process must terminate. In any case after 3 days, the activity D is performed and then the process ends. Is the modeling correct? Or should I do differently?

[image: example of my doubt]

Any type of solution is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your example you would face issue when process B will send 2nd message end event, but there would not be active catch message event on process A.

Use of signal event might be more appropriate as throwing signal not necessarily means that there must be another instance catching it.